# Added UITextField as a subview of UITableViewCell working fine in IOS 6 but in IOS 7 it is not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield

In my app i have a login form, where user enter one field password. so i added a subveiw of `UITextField` in `UITableViewCell` during function call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"loginViewCell"];

UITextField *editableTextField = nil;

// Done Some settings of editableTextField 

// Adding Subview 

[cell addSubview:editableTextField];
```

When user press login button i called a selector function name login

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [loginTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

// Then i travesed in the `subviews` of `cell` and from `UITextField` subview i extract password which was entered by user.

```
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        usernameField = (UITextField *)view;
                    break;
    }
}
```

This is working fine till `IOS 7`

After searching on net i trace the problem that in `IOS 7`  Apple changes the view hierarchy of `UITableViewCell` and now there is additional class inserted `UITableViewCellScrollView`.

I debug my code in my selector function login it is getting the same cell in which i added the `subview` i print the name of `cell.subview` is is showing `UITableViewCellScrollView` previously it was showing `UITableViewCellcontentView` (before `ios7`)

How can I extract the password from `subeview` of  `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Make sure you add subviews to cell's contentView rather than the cell itself.

Comment: If you don't want to subclass UITableView cell, you can reference subview's by tags. Set the tag of the UITextField instance & add it, then you can reference it later by: UITextField * tf = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to subclass your UITableView cell and add a class property that is your UITextField.  Then you could just call `cell.textField.text` instead of searching through the view hierarchy.

The second way would be to search recursively through the entire view hierarchy, not just a single layer of subviews.  (and you should be searching the cell.contentView anyway, bad things happen when you add views as subview's of the cell directly.)

EDIT adding code for searching recursively through view hierarchy.  I do not recommend this method, I recommend subclassing UITableViewCell (it will make your like so much easier), but here you go.

You would call a function like

```
UIView *yourFoundSubview = [self findTextFieldInCell:cell];
```

And that function would be defined:

```
-(UIView*)findTextFieldInCell:(UIView*)input
{
    if([input isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        return input;
    }

    UIView *foundview;
    for(UIView *view in input.subviews)
    {
        foundview = [self findTextFieldInCell:view];
        if(foundview)
        {
            return foundview;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: how to search through entire view hierarchy ? i tried this on `cell.subviews` but it is showing just one view which is `UITableViewCellScrollView`

Comment: Edited to show code for recursive searching through view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is not the right place to add subviews but rather to manipulate them.
You should really create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` having a `@property UITextField` which is added to the cell within the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method.

```
[self.contentView addSubview:self.passwordField];
```

Then you can access this particular `UITextField` with `[cell passwordField]` or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get the subviews of the `UITableViewCellScrollView`.

Instead of adding the textfield to the cell, add the `UITextField` to `cell.contentView`, and look for the `textField` in the subviews of the `cell.contextView`.

I think what would really be best in the long run for your solution though, would be to create a custom `UITableViewCell`, and add the `textField` in there. You could directly access your textfield that way without having to loop through the subviews of the `cell.contentView`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 things:
If you have only have 1 textfield for you entire viewcontroller, you define a property that holds a reference to your passwordTextField

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) UITextField *passwordTextfield;
```

Or, if you have a textfield for each tableviewCell, you could define a collection of UITextFields

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *textFields;
```

then you can reference your passwordTextField with:

```
UITextField *passwordField = self.textFields[PASSWORD_ROW];
```